# GUI: Moving from a config file to a UI, where to start?

Tags: language-agnostic, user-interface, methodology

I'm pretty used to C++ and the basics of the OGL API. I wrote a program using these two that loaded data from a config.txt file to render a scene in an OpenGL window. I am working to make it a little more realtime, and so I'd like to make a user interface. The user would enter data on the fly and see the updates as they are processed (say after clicking an apply button) to an always visible scene in the main of the program.

I have **zero** UI *programming* experience and have searched through the forums here.
I have found some points towards SCALA, C#, and various Python programming methodologies (like pyFLTK). But after reading these forum posts I am still not sure which is the one I need or where to get started.

What would be the best suggestion to move towards creating something for my first description? Not looking to have it move beyond Windows just yet, but is it standard practice to make the UI able to? If so how does that change which I'd choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sticking with Windows then you can use C++Builder from... whoever it's from these days. If you want to increase the cross-platform viability of the product then FPC with [Lazarus](http://lazarus.freepascal.org/) is a good solution, although it will require a different language.

Comment: I'll give this a try, will I be able to embed the OpenGL window in the way I described? (or some kind of renderer).

Comment: You'll need a third-party component, but I'm sure it's doable.

Comment: @user1013515: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10528 http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/OpenGL

Comment: Thank you for the references, I had visited one before. My main question wasn't what was possible, but which would be the best starting implementation. The C++ Builder was what I was trying but I had to uninstall the software. I've no idea why, but after installation, VC++ had some weird error, and my OGL app no longer produces the same output it did before, not sure what changed, but can't seem to undo it. So back to square one.